# vimeo implementation on Phonegap

Tags: json, cordova, vimeo

Does anyone know which API that I need to use for vimeo implementation into phonegap ios/Android app. I'm looking at both the simple and advanced API. The simple one seems to have no player implementation, I can only fetch data about my videos. I want the video to play within my application. The advanced api seems to have some player implementation but also looks like I need to authenticate users. I'm kinda lost in all of this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Check out this plugin solution:

http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.ca/2011/11/video-player-plugin-for-phonegap.html

Comment: Hi Simon, Thanks for the help appreciate it. It is working on Youtube but i need one for Vimeo. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not Simon. I'm A. Magalhães. What is your Phonegap version that you using?

Comment: Hi A. Magalhães, sorry for the wrong name. i am using phonegap 2.1. let me know if there is a solution to integrate vimeo in phonegap. not a mobile browser but in a native way,

Answer (score 0):

1. the Iframe share is just fine with PHONEGAP.
2. If u need to change the player you need a VIMEO pro account and Advanced API
3. If you want to restrict your videos from public then u need Advance API